# Centering widgets on frames

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

My widgets are not centered on the `MainFrame` which uses a `grid` layout. So I've decided to put them on 3 different frames and add them into the `MainFrame`. Still, they are not centered. How to make them be on the squares that I've drawn?

```
from Tkinter import *


class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)#, width = 300, height = 250)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.createFrames()
        self.createCheckBoxes()
        self.createButtons()


    def createButtons(self):
        self.printButton = Button(self.frame0, text = "Print msg", command = self.printMsg)
        self.printButton.grid()

        self.printButton2 = Button(self.frame0, text = "Print msg 2", command = self.printMsg)
        self.printButton2.grid()

        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame2, text = "QUIT", command = self.frame.quit, fg = "red")
        self.quitButton.grid(columnspan = 10)


    def createCheckBoxes(self):
        self.cb1var = IntVar()
        self.cb1 = Checkbutton(self.frame1, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = self.cb1var, command = self.printMsgCb)
        self.cb1.grid()

    def createFrames(self):
        self.frame0 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frame0.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame0.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 10)
        self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 20)
        self.frame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#button commands ----------------------------------
    def printMsg(self):
        print "Clicou no botao"
    def printMsgCb(self):
        print "Check box value = " + str(self.cb1var.get())
#--------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame = MainFrame(root)
root.geometry('1100x600+200+150')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: my draw]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "centered". Do you mean that all of the extra space needs to be on the far right and far left, or that the three columns need to be evenly distributed across the app? Should those inner frames be as close to each other as possible? Also, should they be vertically centered, horizontally centered, or both?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's lose some of the redundant parts that do nothing for the current code. ***Remove***:

```
self.frame0.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame0.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...   
self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
self.frame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Above lines are configuring the *inner* layout of the subframes(`self.frame0`, `self.frame1`, `self.frame2`) which needs no configuration currently.

Then replace:

```
self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 10)
...
self.frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 20)
```

with:

```
self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
...
self.frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

As you shouldn't be needing that large of a grid currently.

Then replace:

```
self.frame.pack()
```

with:

```
self.frame.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
```

to bring your `self.frame` to the vertical center while being expanded horizontally.

Finally uniformly distribute the subframes of `self.frame` horizontally by configuring the columns they're in, by adding:

```
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=True)
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform=True)
```

anywhere after `self.frame` is defined.

Entire code with the changes have been made:

```
from Tkinter import *


class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)#, width = 300, height = 250)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform=True)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

        self.createFrames()
        self.createCheckBoxes()
        self.createButtons()


    def createButtons(self):
        self.printButton = Button(self.frame0, text = "Print msg", command = self.printMsg)
        self.printButton.grid() # add sticky='nsew' optionally

        self.printButton2 = Button(self.frame0, text = "Print msg 2", command = self.printMsg)
        self.printButton2.grid()

        self.quitButton = Button(self.frame2, text = "QUIT", command = self.frame.quit, fg = "red")
        self.quitButton.grid(columnspan = 10)


    def createCheckBoxes(self):
        self.cb1var = IntVar()
        self.cb1 = Checkbutton(self.frame1, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = self.cb1var, command = self.printMsgCb)
        self.cb1.grid()

    def createFrames(self):
        self.frame0 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.frame1 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.frame)
        self.frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

#button commands ----------------------------------
    def printMsg(self):
        print "Clicou no botao"
    def printMsgCb(self):
        print "Check box value = " + str(self.cb1var.get())
#--------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame = MainFrame(root)
root.geometry('1100x600+200+150')
root.mainloop()
```